# Free web "caching" services for a web service

Tags: service

I have a web service on Google App engine whose data is updated on a daily basis.

To minimize bandwidth utilization from mobile clients connecting to it, I'd like to instead have an intermediary site where the clients will be getting their data from, and minimizing hits to my service to once or twice a day only.

Is there such a service I can use? I'd like to explore this "pull" option first, before considering "push" options such as publishing to a blog site or a free website host that doesn't have bandwidth caps.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding this:1) Do you want a service that will host your site/use their bandwidth 2) Do you want a way to make your dynamic site static

Comment: More of the former, but with a pull mechanism like a cache. The 3rd-party service will update its content daily by pulling from my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use the right caching headers, like max-age, expires / e-tag, etc? This will stop mobile clients from trying to refresh more than once a day.

If you're looking for a third party service, check out [mashery.com](http://mashery.com/) . They do a lot more than caching though (traffic reporting and management).

Comment: The mobile client app is also custom developed. True I can set it so that it only connects once a day, but I'd like it to be flexible in case I might need to update data more than once on a particular day.

Comment: If you set the right http cache headers (`e-tag`, `last-modified`, `max-age` or `expires`), you can have the client perform conditional GET requests (`If-Modified-Since`). The web server can then send a not-modified response and skip sending the body of the response...